# Iterating through columns of smartsheet retrieves only first column python

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I am trying to store a dict of all column titles and their ids for future use. However, the iteration of columns stops after the first column.
I am not getting through to other columns.

```py
my_sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet('507.......')
print(my_sheet)
col_id={}
print("\n\ncols:",type(my_sheet.columns))
def get_primary_column_id(columns):
    prim_col_id=-1
    for Mycolumn in columns:
        print(Mycolumn.title)
        col_id[Mycolumn.title]=Mycolumn.id
        if (Mycolumn.primary):
            prim_col_id=Mycolumn.id
            print("primcol",prim_col_id)
    return prim_col_id

primary_column_id = get_primary_column_id(my_sheet.columns)
print("colid",col_id)
```

Output: Below is the part of output from my_sheet

```
At": "2019-07-11T13:46:11+00:00Z", "columns": [{"index": 0, "title": "Mid", "pri
mary": true, "width": 150, "version": 0, "validation": false, "type": "TEXT_NUMB
ER", "id": 984.....}, {"index": 1, "title": "Marketing Director", "width"
: 150, "version": 0, "validation": false, "type": "TEXT_NUMBER", "id": 100.....}, {"index": 2, "title": "Development Lead", "width": 150, "version": 0,
"validation": false, "type": "TEXT_NUMBER", "id": 548.......}, {"index": 3
, "title": "System1", "width": 150, "version": 0, "validation": false, "type": "
TEXT_NUMBER", "id": 323.....}, {"index": 4, "title": "System2", "width":
150, "version": 0, "validation": false, "type": "TEXT_NUMBER", "id": 774....}], "totalRowCount": 3, "accessLevel": "OWNER", "id": 507......, "cr
eatedAt": "2019-05-20T08:52:20+00:00Z", "resourceManagementEnabled": false}
(u'\n\ncols:', <class 'smartsheet.types.TypedList'>)
Mid
(u'primcol', 984.......)
(u'colid', {u'Mid': 984......})
```

Answer (score 0):

Running this same code against my own sheet does print out a list of every column on the sheet with their names and ids. Have you checked the sheet and confirmed it has more than one column?
I did comment out the `print(my_sheet)` statement on the second line as printing out the whole sheet response took up a good amount of space on my terminal. That helped to show me I was getting the whole list of every column on the sheet. Before doing that I was still getting the whole list. Removing it just made it easier to read.

Comment: ya..print(my_sheet) shows all columns but not in the function. Have updated the output with part of the my_sheet response

Comment: @user10257779 When I run this code against a sheet the output of the `col_id` variable looks like this: `colid {'Primary Column': 4113980584159108, 'Column2': 662945437902724, 'Column3': 5166545065273220, 'Column4': 2914745251587972, 'Column5': 7418344878958468, 'Column6': 1788845344745348}`  That is every column on my sheet with a key:value pair for the name of the column and its id number. What is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update here...solved it..Thanks anyways.. removing the  code for finding primary column from the abv section somehow made it iterate through the whole loop